# Example of a non-reflexive Banach space and two sequences

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal {A}, \mu ) $ be a finite measure space and $X$ be a Banach space. The set of all Bochner-integrable functions from $E$ into $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{L}_X^1$.

If $X$ is reflexive, we have the following theorem

> **Theorem 1**
>
> Let $ (f_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal {L}_{X}^1$ is a sequence  with : $$\sup_n \int_{E}{\|f_n\| d\mu} < \infty .$$
> Then there exist $ h _{\infty} \in  \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1 $ and a sub-sequence $ (g_k)_k $ of $(f_n)_n $  such that for every sub-sequence $ (h_m)_m $ of $(g_k)_k$ : $$ \frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}{h_j(t)}\to   h _{\infty}(t) \text{ weakly in }X\text{ a.e. }$$

*Proof* of this result exists in the article "**Infinite-dimensional extension of a theorem of Komlos**" by Erik J. Balder (***Theorem A***).

If $X$ is not reflexive, we have the following theorem

> **Theorem 2**
>
> Let $ (f_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal {L}_{X}^1$ is a sequence  with :
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \bullet~~ \{f_n(t)\}\text{ is relatively weakly compact a.e.,}\\
> \bullet~~ \sup_n \int_{E}{\|f_n\| d\mu} < \infty.\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Then there exist $ h _{\infty} \in  \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1 $ and a sub-sequence $ (g_k)_k $ of $(f_n)_n $  such that for every sub-sequence $ (h_m)_m $ of $(g_k)_k$ : $$ \frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}{h_j(t)}\to   h _{\infty}(t) \text{ weakly in }X\text{ a.e. }$$

*Proof* of this result exists in the article "**Infinite-dimensional extension of a theorem of Komlos**" by Erik J. Balder (***Theorem B***).

**My problem:**

I want an example of a ***non-reflexive Banach space*** and *two sequences*, such that:

- The first sequence is bounded in $\mathcal {L}_{X}^1$ but it does not verify the consequence of Theorem 1.
- The second sequence verifying the hypotheses of Theorem 2 and its consequences.

Comment: The second point is easy: take $f_n \equiv 0$.